# c# Aggregate in mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to get the statistics from my log in mongo using aggregate in C# but I'm always getting the error:

> The group aggregate field 'RecordDate' must be defined as an expression
>   inside an object.

This is my code, can someone tell e what's wrong in the aggreggation?

```
IMongoCollection<LogRecord> myCollection = MongoClient.GetDatabase("DatabaseName").GetCollection<LogRecord>("CollectionName");
List<GroupedData> logSats = myCollection.Aggregate<LogRecord>()
                    .Group<LogRecord, StatsKeys, GroupedData>(
                    t => new StatsKeys
                    {
                        RecordDate= t.RecordDate.ToString("%Y-%m-%d"),
                        Type = t.Type,
                        User = t.UserName
                    },
                    g => new GroupedData
                    {

                        count = g.Count(),
                        Success = g.Count(t => !t.Error),
                        Erros = g.Count(t => t.Error),
                        RecordDate = g.Key.RecordDate,
                        Type = g.Key.Type,
                        User = g.Key.User,
                        AvgTime = g.Average(t => t.FirstStepTime + t.SecondStepTime)
                    }
                    ).ToList();
```

RecordDate in LogRecord is DateTime but in the others it's a string.

Comment: Using `g.Key` directly on the `GroupedData` object worked for me e.g. `Key = g.Key` - is that a possibility? I also encountered issues starting at `ToString("%Y-%m-%d")` just returning the string literal so might be worth checking that is behaving as you expect. I had to change the approach to use three separate assignment statements e.g. `Day = t.RecordDate.Day` but then I could get that to flow to the `GroupedData` stage.

Answer (score 1):

Following Greg Stanley's suggestion I added a StatsKeys variable(in this case, called "Key") to GroupedData class and used Key = g.Key instead and it worked.

```
 IMongoCollection<LogRecord> myCollection = MongoClient.GetDatabase("DatabaseName").GetCollection<LogRecord>("CollectionName");
    List<GroupedData> logSats = myCollection.Aggregate<LogRecord>()
                        .Group<LogRecord, StatsKeys, GroupedData>(
                        t => new StatsKeys
                        {
                            RecordDate= t.RecordDate.ToString("%Y-%m-%d"),
                            Type = t.Type,
                            User = t.UserName
                        },
                        g => new GroupedData
                        {

                            count = g.Count(),
                            Success = g.Count(t => !t.Error),
                            Erros = g.Count(t => t.Error),
                            Key = g.Key,
                            AvgTime = g.Average(t => t.FirstStepTime + t.SecondStepTime)
                        }
                        ).ToList();
```